# Unable to get Jquery script to ignore last two rows in html table

Tags: jquery, html-table, rows

I have a table that dynamically grows in size and then Jquery script to write 'name' attributes used by paypal to each . I use an incrementor per `<tr>` (++r) to add one numeric increment to each paypal field I write, e.g., amount_1, amount_2, etc.

The script works great until I added the line 'delivery costs' which should not be included in the routine of assigning 'name' attributes to the rest of the table rows.

Also, the script runs starting from the bottom line and moving top, I would prefer it starts at the top and run to the bottom - how do I achieve this?

html table:

```
<table id="quote">
    <th>Sign type</th>
    <th>Size</th>
    <th>Qty</th>
    <th>Unit price</th>
    <th>Subtotal</th>
    <th>Cancel</th>
    <tr class="checkoutOptions">
        <td>
            <input class="finalSign" type="hidden" value="123" />Sign name</td>
        <td>40 X 40</td>
        <td>
            <input maxlength="2" class="finalQty" value="5" />
        </td>
        <td class="unitFocus">
            <input class="finalUnitPrice" type="hidden" value="50" />$50</td>
        <td class="subtotal">'+$XX</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="checkoutOptions">
        <td>
            <input class="finalSign" type="hidden" value="123" />Sign name</td>
        <td>40 X 40</td>
        <td>
            <input maxlength="2" class="finalQty" value="5" />
        </td>
        <td class="unitFocus">
            <input class="finalUnitPrice" type="hidden" value="50" />$50</td>
        <td class="subtotal">'+$XX</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="checkoutOptions">
        <td>
            <input class="finalSign" type="hidden" value="123" />Sign name</td>
        <td>40 X 40</td>
        <td>
            <input maxlength="2" class="finalQty" value="5" />
        </td>
        <td class="unitFocus">
            <input class="finalUnitPrice" type="hidden" value="50" />$50</td>
        <td class="subtotal">'+$XX</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="deliveryCost">
        <td><span class="italic">Delivery cost for all items</span>
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td class="subtotal">S$0</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="total">
        <td>Grand total:</td>
        <td colspan="4">
            <input id="pprice" type="hidden" name="amount" maxlength="5" value="" />S$0</td>
        <td>
            <input id="buy_now" type="image" src="/img/buy_button.png" name="submit" alt="PayPal . The safer, easier way to pay online." onclick="optionsFormsReset()" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And the Javascript/jquery:

```
function paypalPasser() {
    var r = 0;
    $("#quote tr:last td:not(:first,:last)").html(function (c) {
        $(this).parent().prevAll().find("td:nth-child(" + (c + 1) + ")").each(function () {
            ++r;
            $(this).find('.finalSign').attr("name", "item_name_" + r + "");
        });
    });
    //reiterate r(reset to 0) & function here for each paypal field
    //on0
    r = 0;
    $("#quote tr:last td:not(:first,:last)").html(function (c) {
        $(this).parent().prevAll().find("td:nth-child(" + (c + 2) + ")").each(function () {
            ++r;
            $(this).find('.finalSize').attr("name", "on0");
        });
    });
    //quantity_
    r = 0;
    $("#quote tr:last td:not(:first,:last)").html(function (c) {
        $(this).parent().prevAll().find("td:nth-child(" + (c + 3) + ")").each(function () {
            ++r;
            $(this).find('.finalQty').attr("name", "quantity_" + r + "");
        });
    });
    //amount_
    r = 0;
    $("#quote tr:last td:not(:first,:last)").html(function (c) {
        $(this).parent().prevAll().find("td:nth-child(" + (c + 4) + ")").each(function () {
            ++r;
            $(this).find('.finalUnitPrice').attr("name", "amount_" + r + "");
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me try to understand your request. When I look into your function paypalPasser, I find a complex combination of selectors, and - for me - unclear usage of the jquery method html:

```
/* first part */

/* selects the the second cell in the last row (there are only three) */
$("#quote tr:last td:not(:first,:last)")

/* from this cell - find parent and from parent all previous elements, 
   this collects all rows except the last one */
$(this).parent().prevAll()

/* from this collection you ask for a specific cell 
   (second cell, because the index c is zero) */
.find("td:nth-child("+(c + 1)+")")

/* inside this cell you look for an element with the class .finalSign */
$(this).find('.finalSign')

/* finally you set / update the name attribute of this input field */
.attr("name", "item_name_"+r+"");
```

As far as I know the [html method](http://api.jquery.com/html/) accepts a function, but this function should return the html to display - in your case inside the second cell of the last row - but this won't work, because your function returns a jquery collection, not a string. So actually you only update the name attribute, not the contents of the cell? If it is like that - you could do something like this.

```
$('#quote').find('.finalSign').each(function(r) {
    $(this).attr("name", "item_name_"+(r + 1)+"");
});
```

Like this you start from top (not from bottom) as you requested, and you ignore all rows without the hidden input fields without complex nested selectors. Same for the following parts of your function. Even if you want to write something inside the cell of the last row, I would modify the renaming as described and do the content update separat.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, I only use the function to alter the 'name' attribute - nothing else. Content is updated via another function and this is the final pass to 'align the data' for passing to Paypal. Let me try your suggestion and report back on the results. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it: **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tomanow/qyhobywu/1/)**

#### HTML

```
<table id="quote">
    <tr>
        <th>Sign type</th>
        <th>Size</th>
        <th>Qty</th>
        <th>Unit price</th>
        <th>Subtotal</th>
        <th>Cancel</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="checkoutOptions">
        <td>
            <input class="finalSign" type="hidden" value="123" />Sign name</td>
        <td>40 X 40</td>
        <td>
            <input maxlength="2" class="finalQty" value="5" />
        </td>
        <td class="unitFocus">
            <input class="finalUnitPrice" type="hidden" value="50" />$50</td>
        <td class="subtotal">'+$XX</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="checkoutOptions">
        <td>
            <input class="finalSign" type="hidden" value="123" />Sign name</td>
        <td>40 X 40</td>
        <td>
            <input maxlength="2" class="finalQty" value="5" />
        </td>
        <td class="unitFocus">
            <input class="finalUnitPrice" type="hidden" value="50" />$50</td>
        <td class="subtotal">'+$XX</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="checkoutOptions">
        <td>
            <input class="finalSign" type="hidden" value="123" />Sign name</td>
        <td>40 X 40</td>
        <td>
            <input maxlength="2" class="finalQty" value="5" />
        </td>
        <td class="unitFocus">
            <input class="finalUnitPrice" type="hidden" value="50" />$50</td>
        <td class="subtotal">'+$XX</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="deliveryCost">
        <td><span class="italic">Delivery cost for all items</span>

        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td class="subtotal">$ 123</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="total">
        <td>Grand total:</td>
        <td colspan="4">
            <input id="pprice" type="hidden" name="amount" maxlength="5" value="" /><span>$ 0</span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input id="buy_now" type="image" src="" name="submit" alt="PayPal . The safer, easier way to pay online." onclick="" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

#### JS

```
function paypalPasser() {

    var $table = $('#quote');
    var fields = {
        name: {
            field: $table.find('.finalSign'),
            prefix: 'item_name_'
        },
        size: {
            field: $table.find('.finalSize'),
            prefix: 'on'
        },
        quantity: {
            field: $table.find('.finalQty'),
            prefix: 'quantity_'
        },
        amount: {
            field: $table.find('.finalUnitPrice'),
            prefix: 'amount_'
        }
    };

    for (var prop in fields) {
        if (fields.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {

            var $item = fields[prop];
            $item.field.each(function (k, v) {
                $(v).attr('name', $item.prefix + k);
            });

        }
    }

    var $row = $table.find('.checkoutOptions');
    $row.each(function (k, v) {
        var $quantity = $(fields.quantity.field.get(k)),
            $price = $(fields.amount.field.get(k)),
            $subtotal = $(v).find('.subtotal'),
            $delivery = $table.find('.deliveryCost'),
            $grandTotal = $table.find('#pprice');

        function setGrandTotal() {
            var total = 0;
            $table.find('.subtotal').each(function (k, v) {
                total += parseFloat($(v).text().split('$ ')[1]);
            });
            $grandTotal.val(total);
            $grandTotal.parent().find('span').text('$ ' + total);
        }

        function setSubtotal() {
            $subtotal.text('$ ' + ($quantity.val() * $price.val()));
            setGrandTotal();
        }
        setSubtotal();
        $quantity.change(function (e) {
            setSubtotal();
        });
    });

}

paypalPasser();
```